# Visual Studio 2013 Coded UI failing to recognise Radio buttons

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2013 to automate some basic tests on a webpage, such as entering and deleting text in text fields within the webpage etc.

One of the tests I'd like to complete, is via the use of Radio buttons, to select gender (M/F/O). However, the click for this selection always fails with an exception:

```
Test Name:    CodedUITestMethod1
Test Outcome: Failed

Result Message: 

Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.FailedToPerformActionOnHiddenControlException: Cannot perform 'SetProperty of Selected with value "True"' on the hidden control. Additional Details: 
TechnologyName:  'Web'
ControlType:  'RadioButton'
TagName:  'INPUT'
Id:  'ContentPlaceHolder1_customers_general1_rblGender_1'
Name:  'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$customers_general1$rblGender'
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0xF004F002
```

I note that there are several instances of similar failures reported on the internet, some to do with Microsoft security patch KB2870699 - which I don't see listed in my patches.

Many of the other reported issues seem to be 'more bespoke' than 'general'.

Is there a 'more general' issue out there that causes this issue, for which there may be a simple fix?

Has this Microsoft security patch KB2870699 been superceeded?

At a loss to see how these Radio buttons don't work while other aspects on the same page under test function as expected.

These particular Radio Buttons, I have never had to function at all.

Answer (score 0):

the error you are given:
"Cannot perform 'SetProperty of Selected with value "True"' on the hidden control"
suggest there is some other control that is blocking the radio button and prevents 
you from setting it.
try checking perhaps there is a toolTip or something related that is blocking your control.

if you could post the rest of the code that might help understanding the problem better.

Comment: The options are radio buttons that can actually be selected, and indicate that they are selected once clicked. However, Coded UI playback throws this exception when replaying. Unfortunately a lot of the code is company confidential, so is not something I can post - which is why I'm trying to look for a 'general' reason why this happens, and for a simple fix. What I've seen so far for this kind of issue, is more detailed though it seems.

Comment: radio buttons can of course be selected, but what i was trying to suggest is the possibilty that during run time some other control is blocking the radio button or the button get's hidden for some other reason, which prevent the playback from setting it's properties.

Comment: Hmm. Something is blocking this selection for sure, as it happens 100% of the time. Which means the test throws an exception everytime, for which I merely comment out that aspect for the moment to test the remaining steps. Frustrating one this one.